# extern "C" и многомодульный проект?

Tags: visual-studio, c++

Пытаюсь собрать многомодульный проект.

visual 2012.

Подключаю так
заголовочные файлы:

module.h

исходный код:
module.cpp
main.cpp

```
// Вот здесь правильно? Так сделано в прекомпилированном заголовке.
module.cpp
[[
    include "module.h"
]]

module.h
[[

// Вот такие включения идут нормально
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

//Но есть библиотека mpir.
//И там есть код

extern "C"
{
int __gmp_printf (const char *, ...);
}

//Функция __gmp_printf определена в .lib файле.
#pragma comment(lib,"mpir.lib")

// Дальше её вызываю 
struct class_
{
class_()
{
__gmp_printf("text");
}
};

Лезут ошибки
libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl _invalid_parameter(unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned int,unsigned __int64)" (?_invalid_parameter@@YAXPEBG00I_K@Z) уже определен в LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl _invoke_watson(unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned short const *,unsigned int,unsigned __int64)" (?_invoke_watson@@YAXPEBG00I_K@Z) уже определен в LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: _call_reportfault уже определен в LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: _get_invalid_parameter_handler уже определен в LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: _initp_misc_invarg уже определен в LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: _invalid_parameter уже определен в LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: _invoke_watson уже определен в LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: _set_invalid_parameter_handler уже определен в LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>libcmt.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __pInvalidArgHandler уже определен в LIBCMTD.lib(invarg.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(crt0init.obj) : warning LNK4098: библиотека по умолчанию "libcmt.lib" противоречит использованию других библиотек; используйте параметр /NODEFAULTLIB:library

Пробовал включение .lib класть в module.cpp и main.cpp: ничего не помогает.
class_ вынести в main.cpp тоже самое.

]]

main.cpp
[[

#include "module.h"
class_ d;

int main()
{
return 1;
}

]]
```

Comment: А пробовали не подключать `#pragma comment(lib,"mpir.lib")` ? Судя по выводу, оно уже подключено.

Comment: Функция лежит внутри .lib. без неё идет "не разрешенный внешний символ".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Похоже, что приложение собирается в релизе, а библиотека в отладке или наоборот. Каждая часть тянет за собой свою версию рантайма и происходят конфликты. Надо, чтобы у библиотеки и приложения была одинаковая конфигурация.

Comment: Вот правильный ответ, если хочется сделать так как надо.

Comment: Заработало при release - библиотека времени выполнения многопоточная.
Я эти настройки пробовал, с самого начала :(( , видимо невнимательно.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если очень хочется заставить это работать любыми средствами то есть  `/FORCE:MULTIPLE` который нужно добавить в опции линковщика. [/FORCE (Force File Output)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70abkas3.aspx).

Comment: Компилируется, но выдаёт:

Debug assertion Failed!
expression: pHead->nBlockUse == nBlockUse

Comment: Это уже что-то с совместимостью программы и библиотеки. Если можешь, собери их в одной версии студии с одинаковыми параметрами. Тогда и  /FORCE:MULTIPLE не понадобится.